# 'prebuild' scripts in project.json doesn't run

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx, project.json

I have a .NET 5 web application using the DNX framework, and I want to run 'npm install', 'bower install' and others, whenever I build the project.

Right now I'm able to do so on publish, using 'prepublish', but it doesn't seem to work with 'prebuild', although I saw it is possible [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file)

What I have now:

```
"scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "tsd install", "gulp min" ]
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem - prebuild works from a command line "dnu build", but from a Visual Studio build it doesn't get hooked.

Comment: confirmed, although I'm still on beta5 due to signalr not yet being caught up.

Answer (score 11):

As of RC1, [you have to "produce outputs"](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/432) to pipe the build through `dnu`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: With whatever tooling/framework is most up to date in November 2016, this checkbox isn't there.

Comment: The latest tooling/framework has moved on - DNX is deprecated now.

Answer (score 10):

I know this question is a bit older, but google lead me to it. As of 06/19/2016, you should use `precompile` instead of `prebuild`. The new documentation for the `project.json` file is available at https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#scripts.

The valid script options for the project.json file are:

- precompile
- postcompile
- prepublish
- postpublish

And Microsoft has already released an announcement stating they will be reverting back to the old `.csproj` format. You can read about it on the [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/23/changes-to-project-json/).

> The first wave of this change will happen in the Visual Studio “15” RTM: when opening any .NET Core project in Visual Studio, it will automatically convert from .xproj to .csproj, moving the assets from the project.json file into configuration files and the .csproj file. We will also provide a tool for converting applications using the .NET command line tools as well.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked for `beta5` but DNX have some documentation about the supported scripts [right here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file#scripts).

Basically this:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "echo before building",
    "postbuild": "echo after building",
    "prepack": "echo before packing",
    "postpack": "echo after packing",
    "prerestore": "echo before restoring packages",
    "postrestore": "echo after restoring packages"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Stajs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33913735/213343) is correct but another step may be needed when working with TypeScript, which seems to be the case here.

By default, Visual Studio compiles the TypeScript sources before it pipes the build through dnu. So if there are new tsd type definitions or other references that will only work if `tsd install` is run first, the build will fail. It's a catch 22.

To prevent Visual Studio from running the TypeScript transpilation, you also have to **uncheck** the `Compile TypeScript on build` checkbox on the **Properties > Build** page.

Note that this only makes sense if you add TypeScript compilation yourself to your gulp or grunt file.

Comment: With whatever tooling/framework is most up to date in November 2016, this option isn't there.