# Copy content files to output directory of DNX Console app via project.json

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, dnx, project.json

I've just started working with DNX 1.0.0-rc1-update1 in VS2015. My first app is a 'Console Application (package)' project. Everything works, except NLog logging. I suspect it's because the NLog.config doesn't get copied to the output folder. How can I tell VS to copy this file to the output folder via project.json?

I've tried adding a 'resource' variable like this but it doesn't work:

**project.json**

```
...
"resource":"NLog.config",
...
```

**EDIT 1:**
I'm using dnx451 so compatibility is not an issue.

**EDIT 2:**
I added the following to **project.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "postbuild": [
      "%project:Directory%/../scripts/copy_resources.bat \\\"%project:Directory%\\\" \\\"%project:Directory%/../artifacts/bin/%project:Name%/%project:Version%/dnx451\\\""
    ] 
  }
```

**copy_resources.bat**

```
echo "Running script" >> C:\logs\log.txt
echo %1 >> C:\logs\log.txt
echo %2 >> C:\logs\log.txt

xcopy %1\NLog.config %2 /U /Y
```

There's nothing in the output window in VS to indicate that the script was actually run. Furthermore, log.txt is empty.

How can I debug the build process?

Comment: Have you experimented with path to your NLog.config in project.json? Approach you applied should work in general: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972571/image-as-resource-in-asp-net-5-class-library

Comment: You may need to update your title. What you tried in your project.json file will compile `NLog.config` into the assembly. What you are describing in the post is to copy the `NLog.config` to the output directory.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing wrong.  Only thing I can think of is NLog does not support DNXCORE50 so remove it from your project.json.  Microsoft's own sample might be of help.  https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/tree/1.0.0-rc1/samples/SampleApp

Answer (score 23):

In the meantime, .NET Core RTM was published.

Now, the current way to get stuff copied to the output folder is using the [`buildOptions` section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#buildoptions) in `project.json`.

There's the [`copyToOutput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#copytooutput) option which you can use like this:

Before:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  // more stuff
}
```

After:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "copyToOutput": { "includeFiles": [ "NLog.config" ] }
  },

  // more stuff
}
```

Comment: This should be the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: For me just this was necessary: 
`"buildOptions": { "copyToOutput": "file.txt"  }`

Answer (score 10):

Use `copyToOutput` inside `buildOptions`:

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "copyToOutput":  "NLog.config" 
  }
}
```

or for multiple files declare an array:

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "copyToOutput":  ["NLog.config", "testdata\\"]
  }
}
```

To copy a directory remember to add the trailing `\\`.

Answer (score 3):

> By default all code files in a directory containing a project.json are
>   included in the project. You can control this with the include/exclude
>   sections of the project.json.

More info: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/projects.html#including-excluding-files

You use the **content** section of `project.json` like this

```
{
  "content": [
    "NLog.config"
  ]
}
```

Now the documentation says that the file should have been copied by default as the content default if * (wildcard for all files), but you can force it with the explicit stating of the file you want in the **content** section.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I can't find NLog.config in the output folder (...\MyProject\artifacts\bin\MyProject\Debug\app) nor can I see any console output. I know for sure NLog works if I configure it in the code.

Comment: Ok. seeing as the content copy route is not working you could try this one. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33952463/5233410 where they use a `postbuild` script to move files (in this case dlls) over to output directory.

Comment: This property is deprecated, the answer from @ChristianSpecht has the new property

Answer (score 2):

I think it is broken in RC1. I was also looking how to get content files copied to the output folder, and found [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/3291) that looks similar to what we are seeing.

As @Nkosi points out, the default for `content` is `**/*` (you can see via the docs link he provided, and also by the [schema](http://json.schemastore.org/project)).

As for your `postbuild` step, you can get it going by ["producing outputs"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220663/prebuild-scripts-in-project-json-doesnt-run/33913735#33913735).