# Equivalent of Copy to Output Directory for DNX applications

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, dnx

I have a Dnx451 MVC web application and I want to copy a `.txt` file to the output directory to make it easier to copy my application files.

I have added the file to my project at the same level as `project.json` and added the following to my `project.json` file.

```
"content": [
   "file.txt"
]
```

But when I build the application the file isn't copied to the output location. In previous versions, I would have just set the Copy to Output Directory option in the file properties, but that doesn't exist in a DNX project.

What is the equivalent process of Copy to Output Directory to get a content file copied to the output directory?

Comment: Not sure why you got down-voted, seems a legit question to me. Got you back to zero now at least.

Comment: @Stajs I don't know either, guess not many people are using DNX yet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482103/copy-content-files-to-output-directory-of-dnx-console-app-via-project-json/35834765

Comment: @Stajs that doesn't really answer the question as I'm doing what was suggested in the answer. The comment to then use a postbuild script to copy the file, while it works, is not exactly a terrific solution.

Comment: Yeah, it was meant to be a "look, here's someone else with a similar question" rather than "here's an answer".